# On back pressed, Alert dialogue is visible for very little time and the app closes. How to solve this problem

Tags: android

"On clicking back button My Alert dialogue box is showing up for a very small time and the activity ends. My code is:"

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    showAlertDialog();
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("WARNING")
         .setCancelable(false)
         .setMessage("You won't be able to get saved messages.")
         .setPositiveButton("exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.create().show();
}
```

I want my alert to be shown on clicking the back button and user can choose whether stay or finish.

Comment: Remove `super.onBackPressed();` from your code.

Comment: I suggest you to consider edge cases, check if you really want to display the dialog first, and then display it, otherwise call `super.onBackPressed()`. Something like: `if (isToShowDialog) showAlertDialog() else super.onBackPressed()`

Comment: thanks man. It worked.

Comment: Close the question please.